# Taking means of duplicated IDs

Tags: r

I have a dataset "rna", which is thousands of rows that I have simplified below. There are rows that contain both the same "Sample" and "Ensembl", but have different expression values. I need a way to take the mean of the expression values for rows that have both the same sample ID and ensembl. Rows that contain unique combinations of "Sample" and "Ensembl" should not have expression values changed. I've tried to write a for loop with selecting for duplicated rows, but I can't figure out how to pair them in order to take the Expression means. "org-rna" matrix shows what I want the result to be. TYIA

```
rna = data.frame("Sample" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), "Ensembl" =  c("ENSG00000174010", "ENSG00000174010", "ENSG00000192738", "ENSG00000147183", "ENSG00000147183",
    "ENSG00000231267"), "Expression" = c(1, 2, 3.5, 1, 6, 8))


org_rna = data.frame("Sample" = c(1, 1, 2,3), "Ensembl" = c("ENSG00000174010", "ENSG00000192738", "ENSG00000147183", 
           "ENSG00000231267"), "Expression" =c(1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 8))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to a `tidyverse` solution you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

rna %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(Sample, Ensembl) %>% 
  summarise(Expression = mean(as.numeric(Expression)), .groups = "drop")
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Sample Ensembl         Expression
  <chr>  <chr>                <dbl>
1 1      ENSG00000174010        1.5
2 1      ENSG00000192738        3.5
3 2      ENSG00000147183        3.5
4 3      ENSG00000231267        8
```

Note: I converted your matrix into a `tibble`/`data.frame` which is easier to work on.

You need to group by `Sample` and `Ensemble` and calculate the `mean`.

Answer (score 2):

Or could use `base R`

```
aggregate(Expression ~ ., type.convert(rna, as.is = TRUE), mean)
```

Comment: `type.convert` looks quite useful. Didn't know that one.